# The Knight and the Maze 2

Tags: mazes, knight-moves

I've decided to make another knight and maze puzzle. I felt like I rushed the last one [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38324/the-knight-and-the-maze) because I thought of the idea right before the end of maze fortnight and wanted to submit something in time.

This time I've put a bit more effort in order to try and make the maze a bit more difficult. I have very much appreciated the comments and suggestions on the previous puzzle and have tried to incorporate them here. I hope you enjoy the puzzle.

To refresh, shown below is a grid of blue and white squares with a knight in the upper left hand corner and a dark green square in the lower right hand corner.

Your task is to guide the knight from its starting position to the dark green square using regulation chess knight moves.

The knight may **only** visit white squares to reach its goal.

[image: knight_maze_2]

Comment: Easier solution for the green at least. Put a letter in it, like "E" or something.

Comment: Why do I keep missing these?! :(

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here are all 48 solutions to the maze with no repeated squares (shortest first):

> [image]

The maze actually has some isolated or unreachable components, and one component that is isolated unless you pass through the goal cell:

> [image]

Comment: Wow, great effort. +1. So the first one looks like that given by Arth. Is that correct?

Comment: @hexomino Correct.

Comment: Pumping the maze into my solver from the last one yields the same as @Arth's an optimal solution.

Comment: I find it curious that a grand total of 0 solutions go through the little island (backwards short L) just left of the exit.

Comment: @Goinghamateur I updated my answer with a plot of the connected components in the maze so you can see why.

Comment: @2012rcampion cool stuff dude

Comment: I've accepted this answer because I very much like the thorough analysis, especially on which squares can/cannot be visited.

Comment: Surely this answer deserves a bounty!

Comment: Great to see the orange connected component which ALMOST reaches the goal.

Answer (score 13):

If you take the directions on a clock as the possible moves, 1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11:

> 4,5,2,1,5,5,8,7,4,5,5,5,5,5,1,1,2,2,2,5,5,4,1,5,5,8,7,7,5,5,2,4,5,5

Will do it

> [image: solution]

Which is 34 moves in total.

Comment: Yeah, that's the best I find too.

Comment: My computer also says that this is the shortest solution.

Answer (score 9):

Here is **a** solution to the maze:

> [image]

Comment: * Here is `a` solution to the maze.. +1 though :P

Comment: Well done. That was very quick again. You are obviously very good at these. +1 from me but I may hold out for the optimal solution for the tick.

Comment: @Arth My computer finds 48 distinct solutions that don't repeat any squares.